# Facebook log in error 400

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am logging in into facebook in this way:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];


return YES;
 }



 - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
  {
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error) {
            // We have a valid session
            //NSLog(@"User session found");

            // Initiate a Facebook instance
            self.facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                             initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID
                             andDelegate:nil];

            // Store the Facebook session information
            self.facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
            self.facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
        }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        // Clear out the Facebook instance
        self.facebook = nil;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}



if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
 }

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
         openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
      annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
self.openedURL = url;
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
 }
```

...and I get the error: Error: HTTP status code: 400

I have set up the URL scheme in the plist. Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the App Dashboard. Look at your Basic Settings. Your Sandbox Mode may be set to Enabled. The errors should go away when your app is out of Sandbox mode.